# ReactのJSX内でmap()を使用した際のエラー

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs

### 概要

現在、React + Pusherでリアルタイムのチャット機能を実装していますが、jsxの部分で下記のエラーが発生しました。
具体的には、取得した全メッセージの内容をjsx内で`map()`を使用して表示しているのですがそこでエラーが発生しています。
自分なりに色々調べて`Array.from()`でオブジェクトを配列に変換しましたが、解決せず…。
どなたか解決方法のご教授お願い致します。

＜Chat.get()でconsole.log()した結果＞
`useEffect`内の`Chat.get()`で下記の様な、データベースに保存されたチャットの内容がバックエンドのLaravelから返ってきます。
これをjsx内(`messageList`)で`Array.from(messages).map()`で回しています。

```
{messages: Array(10)}
messages: Array(10)
0:
id: 3
board_id: "ldqc10ol"
user_id: "a"
message: "hello"
created_at: "2020-02-14 09:16:27"
updated_at: "2020-02-14 09:16:27"
__proto__: Object
1: {id: 4, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "d", created_at: "2020-02-14 09:21:23", …}
2: {id: 5, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "l", created_at: "2020-02-14 09:28:25", …}
3: {id: 6, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "kkkk", created_at: "2020-02-14 09:38:07", …}
4: {id: 7, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "あ", created_at: "2020-02-14 09:56:05", …}
5: {id: 8, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "aaaaaa", created_at: "2020-02-14 10:05:55", …}
6: {id: 9, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "a", created_at: "2020-02-14 10:46:31", …}
7: {id: 10, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "a", created_at: "2020-02-14 10:47:22", …}
8: {id: 11, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "a", created_at: "2020-02-14 10:52:25", …}
9: {id: 12, board_id: "ldqc10ol", user_id: "a", message: "a", created_at: "2020-02-14 10:53:46", …}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

### エラーの内容

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {messageList}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

### 該当のコード

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import styled from 'styled-components'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog'
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions'
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle'
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider'
import TextsmsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Textsms'
import TelegramIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Telegram'

import Chat from './../../../models/Chat'
import User from './../../../models/User'
import Board from './../../../models/Board'

import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

Pusher.logToConsole = true

const pusher = new Pusher('*******', {
    cluster: 'ap3',
    forceTLS: true
});

const ChatDialog = props => {
    const { open, onClose, fullScreen } = props
    const [msg, setMsg] = React.useState('')
    const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([])
    const userID = useSelector(state => state.UserReducer.userID)
    let isChanged = true

    useEffect(() => {
        const channelName = 'chat-' + Board.getBoardID()
        const channel = pusher.subscribe(channelName)

        channel.bind('App\\Events\\ChatMessageReceived', data => {
            setMessages([...messages, data])
        })
        return () => {
            channel.unbind('App\\Events\\ChatMessageReceived')
        }
    }, [setMessages, messages])

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = JSON.parse(User.get('token')).token
        const boardID = Board.getBoardID()

        if (token) {
            Chat.get(token, boardID)
                .then(res => {
                    setMessages(res.data.messages)
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                })
        }
    }, [isChanged])

    const handleOnChangeMsg = e => {
        setMsg(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleSendMsg = () => {
        const token = JSON.parse(User.get('token')).token
        const boardID = Board.getBoardID()

        if (token) {
            Chat.send(token, boardID, msg)
                .then(res => {
                    setMsg('')
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                })
        }
    }

    let messageList = (
        Array.from(messages).map((msg, i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
                {msg.user_id === userID ? <UserMsg>{msg[i]}</UserMsg> : <Msg>{msg[i]}</Msg>}
            </React.Fragment>
        ))
    )

    const fullDialog = (
        <Dialog
            fullScreen
            open={open}
            scroll="paper"
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
            <Flex>
                <StyledDialogTitle><StyledTextsmsIcon /><Span>チャット</Span></StyledDialogTitle>
                <StyledDialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={onClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
                        <Span>閉じる</Span>
                    </Button>
                </StyledDialogActions>
            </Flex>
            <DialogContent>
                <Textarea placeholder="メッセージを入力" onChange={handleOnChangeMsg} value={msg}></Textarea>
                <StyledIconButton onClick={handleSendMsg}><StyledTelegramIcon /></StyledIconButton>
            </DialogContent>
            <MessageArea>
                {messages.length === 0 ? <p>メッセージがありません</p> :
                    { messageList }
                }
            </MessageArea>
        </Dialog >
    )
    const nonFullDialog = (
        <Dialog
            open={open}
            scroll="paper"
            fullWidth={true}
            maxWidth="sm"
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
            <Flex>
                <StyledDialogTitle><StyledTextsmsIcon /><Span>チャット</Span></StyledDialogTitle>
                <StyledDialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={onClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
                        <Span>閉じる</Span>
                    </Button>
                </StyledDialogActions>
            </Flex>
            <DialogContent>
                <Textarea placeholder="メッセージを入力" onChange={handleOnChangeMsg} value={msg}></Textarea>
                <StyledIconButton onClick={handleSendMsg}><StyledTelegramIcon /></StyledIconButton>
            </DialogContent>
            <MessageArea>
                {messages.length === 0 ? <p>メッセージがありません</p> :
                    { messageList }
                }
            </MessageArea>
        </Dialog >
    )

    return (
        <>
            {fullScreen === true ? fullDialog : nonFullDialog}
        </>
    )
}

const Flex = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #224272;
`
const Textarea = styled.textarea`
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #224272;
`
const Span = styled.span`
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: white;
`

const StyledDialogTitle = styled(DialogTitle)`
    color: white;
`
const DialogContent = styled.div`
    height: 45px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
`
const MessageArea = styled.div`
    height: 450px;
`
const StyledDialogActions = styled(DialogActions)`

`
const StyledIconButton = styled(IconButton)`
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 35px;
`

const StyledTextsmsIcon = styled(TextsmsIcon)`
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 3px;
`
const StyledTelegramIcon = styled(TelegramIcon)`
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
`

const Msg = styled.p`
    width: 100%
    text-align: left;
`
const UserMsg = styled.p`
    width: 100%
    text-align: right;
`

export default ChatDialog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`messageList`の周りに余計な`{ }`があるのが原因です。

```
            {messages.length === 0 ? <p>メッセージがありません</p> :
                { messageList }
            }
```

このような箇所が2箇所ありますが、`messageList`の周りの`{ }`を取り除いて次のようにするとエラーが消えると思います。

```
            {messages.length === 0 ? <p>メッセージがありません</p> :
                messageList
            }
```

JSX内では`{ }`は任意の式を埋め込むための構文であり、この場合は`messages.length === 0 ? <p>メッセージがありません</p> : messageList`が式です。これは`条件式 ? 真の場合 : 偽の場合`という構文を持つ条件演算子ですから、条件式が偽の場合に表示されるのは`messageList`であることになります。これは配列なので、こうすれば意図した挙動になります。

当初の`{ messageList }`では、これは「`messageList`を描画する」ではなく「`{ messageList }`を描画する」という意味になります。ここでの`{ }`はJSX中で使う`{ }`とは異なる意味を持っています（この位置はJSX式ではないため）。これはオブジェクトリテラルであり、`{ messageList }`は「`messageList`というプロパティを持つオブジェクト」という意味になります。そのため、Reactが「オブジェクトを描画しようとしている」としてエラーを発生させるのです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！これでチャットのメッセージ一覧が表示される様になりました。しかし、メッセージの送信をした瞬間にまた同じエラーが表示されるようになりました…。もしお分かりいただける様であれば、ご回答いただけると幸いです。

Comment: すみません！解決しました！Pusherから受け取った情報をの入れ方を間違っていました！ありがとうございました！